# почему не получается удалить дубликаты postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

есть   такая таблица следующего вида:

| "Date" | "Trade_ID" | "tovar_ID" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | огурцы |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | огурцы |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | огурцы |
| 2021-04-10 | склад1 | помидоры |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | помидоры |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | груши |
| 2021-04-10 | склад2 | огурцы |
| 2021-04-10 | склад3 | огурцы |
| 2021-05-10 | склад1 | огурцы |
| 2021-05-10 | склад2 | огурцы |
| 2021-05-10 | склад1 | огурцы |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад3 | груши |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад2 | помидоры |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад1 | помидоры |
| 2021-05-10 | cклад1 | огурцы |
| 2021-06-10 | cклад1 | сливы |
| 2021-06-10 | cклад1 | сливы |
| 2021-07-10 | cклад1 | сливы |
| 2021-07-10 | cклад1 | сливы |
| 2021-08-10 | cклад1 | сливы |
| 2021-08-10 | cклад1 | сливы |

на основании этой таблицы хочу сделать комбинацию уникальных пересечений,однако cross join создает дубликаты для слив? как не странно по остальным все в порядке. как это поправить ?

вот запросик:

```
    with 
uniq_1 as (select distinct "Trade_ID" as q
           from test_table_12),
uniq_2 as (select distinct "Tovar_ID" as s
           from test_table_12)

    select u_2.s,
       u_1.q
from uniq_2 u_2
cross join uniq_1 u_1
where u_2.s > u_1.q
```

и что выдается:

| s | q |
| --- | --- |
| огурцы | cклад3 |
| огурцы | cклад2 |
| огурцы | cклад1 |
| груши | cклад3 |
| груши | cклад2 |
| груши | cклад1 |
| помидоры | cклад3 |
| помидоры | cклад2 |
| помидоры | cклад1 |
| сливы | **cклад3** |
| сливы | **cклад2** |
| сливы | **склад3** |
| сливы | **склад1** |
| сливы | **склад2** |
| сливы | **cклад1** |

Comment: у тебя часть складов начинается с латинской `c`

Comment: похоже вы правы, как это проверяется? ведь сливы тоже могли быть с ошибкой

Comment: поиск по LIKE '%с%' ?